# Bash - here doc read input value from another user

Tags: bash, shell-script, read, here-document

I have a here document inside a bash script. I want to read a value from it like that :

```
su myUser<<SESSION
set -x 
echo -n "Enter your name and press [ENTER]: "
read name
echo "the name is $name"
SESSION
```

But when I launch this script from another user, bash does not stop himself to wait for an input and ignore the `read` command.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As L. Scott Johnson [correctly found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524450/116858), the `read` reads from standard input.  The standard input in the shell that `su` runs is connected to the here-document, so the `read` reads the literal string `echo "the name is "` (note that since the here-document is unquoted, the `$name` has already been expanded to an empty string, or to whatever value it had in the calling shell).

Here is the same thing, but with a quoted here-document, and an extra line outputting `$name` again:

```
su username <<'SESSION'
set -x
echo -n "Enter your name and press [ENTER]: "
read name
echo "the name is $name"
echo "What I read was $name"
SESSION
```

The output would be

```
Password:
+ echo -n Enter your name and press [ENTER]:
Enter your name and press [ENTER]: + read name
+ echo What I read was echo "the name is $name"
What I read was echo "the name is $name"
```

To correctly do this, you can't have `read` reading from standard input.  Instead, open a new file descriptor as a copy of standard input, and get `read` to read from that:

```
su username 3<&0 <<'SESSION'
set -x
echo -n "Enter your name and press [ENTER]: "
read name <&3
echo "the name is $name"
SESSION
```

If the shell of the other user is `bash` or `ksh`, then `read name <&3` may be replaced by `read -u3 name`.

Note however that you can't expect the `name` variable to be set in the shell calling `su` as a child shell can't modify the environment (variables etc.) of a parent shell.

Comment: Nice explanation, but, consider that we have a large heredoc script to be executed remotely then at some point we need the confirmation to continue the execution of the remaining of the script, how to properly do that ?

Comment: @Enissay By some variant of the code, I show at the end. Or simply by transferring the script over to the remote host and running it there.  However, it's quite seldom that much of a script has to run remotely. It's more common that parts of the script do user interaction locally and then use `ssh` to do a few things on the remote host, possibly processing the data locally.

Comment: Noted, indeed, it will be easier to change the logic to make it more local

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't ignore the read command; it executes it and reads stdin. Then the line `echo "the name is $name` is read (from stdin) and assigned to $name.

```
su myUser<<SESSION
set -x 
echo -n \"Enter your name and press [ENTER]: \"
read name
someUser
echo \"the name is \$name\"
SESSION
```

output:

```
+ echo -n '"Enter' your name and press '[ENTER]:' '"'
-n "Enter your name and press [ENTER]: "
+ read name
+ echo '"the' name is 'someUser"' 
"the name is someUser"
```

Comment: You're right, I understand now :)